# How to override a function call in functions.php?

Tags: plugin-development, api

In functions.php of a theme makes a call to `show_admin_bar(false)` which hides admin bar in front end:

```
if (!is_admin())
{
    wp_deregister_style( 'bp-admin-bar' );
    if ( function_exists( 'show_admin_bar' ) )
    {
        show_admin_bar( false );
        remove_action( 'bp_init', 'bp_core_load_buddybar_css' );
    }
}
```

I want to make admin bar appear in front end for the `admin` users. To do this, I added the following code to a plugin:

```
add_action('plugins_loaded', 'show_admin_bar_to_admins', 100);
function show_admin_bar_to_admins()
{
    if (current_user_can('manage_options')) {
        show_admin_bar(true);
    }
}
```

But this call didn't make a difference. I put `100` as the priority value such in order to make this function to be called later than the call inside `functions.php`. But it didn't make a difference.

Is there a way to make a function call inside a plugin to be executed later than the call inside `functions.php`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First off: This Theme is so doing it wrong. One should not simply stuff plain calls in functions.php files. Those should be wrapped and hook. Best to `after_setup_theme()`. You could btw try the same hook.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to show or hide the admin bar is by hooking into `show_admin_bar` filter, and specifying the conditions you need in the filter function:

```
add_filter('show_admin_bar', 'ad_show_admin_bar');

function ad_show_admin_bar($show) {
    // show front-end admin bar for admins only
    if(current_user_can('manage_options')) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

This will take care of adding necessary scripts and styles for the admin bar as well.